# PHP: Replace "/" with "\" in URL

Tags: php, str-replace

How do I replace "/" in a PHP string like this?

```
C:\files\mybundle/files/example.pdf
```

My desired output:

```
C:\files\mybundle\files\example.pdf
```

This does NOT work:

```
$urlFormatted = str_replace('/', '\', $string)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited :)

```
 $urlFormatted = str_replace('/', '\\', $string)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it in following manner:-

```
 $urlFormatted = str_replace('/', '\\', $string)
```

Also

```
$urlFormatted = preg_replace('[/]', '\\', $data) ;
```